# "Audit" review item showed "protected", revealed as audit

Tags: bug, review-audits

I got a review item that showed 0 answers and 0 votes, but with a "protected" status, which clearly revealed it to be an "audit" item. It was obvious that it was an old, disguised post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was obvious to you because you were paying attention to things like why a question with no answers or votes would be protected.

That you were paying attention means the audit was successful for what it is attempting to do, namely ensure the reader is paying at least the slightest bit of attention.

Audits are *not* there to ensure reviewers are always acting appropriately, understand when actions should or should not be taken, etc.  Rather they're pretty much there to ensure that the reviewer isn't a bot, or acting without even reading the content.

Comment: That's an interesting perspective I hadn't considered. Thanks!

Comment: That's were the audit fail : I'm not a robot and I already get banned for review. Do I pay attention ? I think, but the audit system thinks I'm not. Moreover : The explanation why the answer was wrong is never obvious. If you fear robot, add human challenge in doubt. If you fear the human didn't pay attention, explain him why you think like that and ask him a written response why he made this 'bad' answer ? Banning user from review won't make them better reviewer?