# New to reviewing edit suggestions: dealing with puzzling edit suggestions

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

This question is not about "[edit hunting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260268/edit-hunting-and-possible-reputation-farming-how-should-i-react)". Here, I've seen two suggestions that are completely unclear to me in what they are intending:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8065969
2. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8066046

In No. 1, the correction in the title "D like" seems too far away from what the OP originally wanted to say - or am I not "inside" enough to catch "D like"? Then, what does the suggestion "all the datas imag gets the dates" intend to improve? What should it clarify? Then, down in the code, there is "this is the naming this willing". Here again, would the code even work with this words inserted? Finally, why is there "solution i 5 5" added? I can't find anything meaningful about this with an Internet search engine.

Similar with No. 2: "the nopcommerce site to makes this addapi" is grammatically poor and not understandable. And so on.

Both suggestions propose changes that either are worthless, or I don't understand them.

In order not to do some harm, I've skipped them. What do you suggest, is it better to reject with less hesitation, even if it could be the case you don't get some specific vocabulary? Basically I'd like to honor the editor's work.

In the meantime, both suggestions have been rejected by others.

Comment: The don't add anything to do the question and so should be rejected. It's not your job to edit people's edits.

Comment: Those look like audits. Yes you should have rejected them, look more closely they're utter nonsense.

Comment: @Mat, thx a lot. I see now, [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251248/audit-review-item-showed-protected-revealed-as-audit) is more about audits. They seem to happen in all review queues. I see now how "utter nonsense" looks like, and how it feels puzzling. Specific vocabulary wouldn't do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if they were audits, I'm actually **glad** that you decided to skip them because you were unsure.  This is the sort of thing you *should* do if you're not sure about what to do in a review; [learn to love that "Skip" button.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/1079354)

That said, in general those sorts of edits should be rejected as vandalism or spam.  It may be the case that you don't understand the code in the question, but in at least the first example, it takes runnable Python code and makes it...not runnable.

Any edit that makes large swathes of changes for seemingly spammy or unclear reasons should be rejected.  But if you're unsure, skip.

Comment: There are good references in your answer that show me more about. Thanks a lot. It's good to hear that being cautious is the right thing.